# How to check if variable has syntax and how to split this into a array?

Tags: php

I have the following string "L{id_extern}S{LocationId}" from a field of my database.

This string is the accepted syntax of a input field.

In this example only Inputs should accepts which meets "**L**something**S**something"

For Example

```
<input name="myinput" value="12345"> - is not correct
<input name="myinput" value="L12345"> - is not correct
<input name="myinput" value="L123S45"> - is correct
```

I have to compare the value (12345) with the syntax string.

The part between the "{...}" could have unlimited (1 is min required) numbers and letters.

At first I need to split the syntax-String and make it available in a multidimensional array for example

```
$myArray['placeholder1']=id_extern;
$myArray['placeholder2']=LocationId;
```

**How I can split the string into a kind of this array?**

**How I can compare the value of my Input field with my wanted syntax L{id_extern}S{LocationId} ?** I think pregmatch could help, but I have no idea how it could work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do a [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which with the following regex requires at least 1 (but multiple are possible) character which is a letter a-z or A-Z or a number from 0-9 between `L` and `S` and after `S`

something like:

```
<?php

$strings = ['12345', 'L12345', 'L1S1', 'LS1',  'L123S45', 'L1x23S4yZY5', 'L1x!23S4y5'];

foreach($strings as $string) {
    $hasMatches = preg_match_all('/^L([0-9a-zA-Z]+)S([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    if(filter_var($hasMatches, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) { // converts $hasMatches to boolean
        echo 'THERE IS A MATCH: "' . $matches[0][0] . '"' . "\n";
        echo '1st part: ' . $matches[0][1] . "\n";
        echo '2nd part: ' . $matches[0][2] . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

the above output is:

```
THERE IS A MATCH: "L1S1"
1st part: 1
2nd part: 1

THERE IS A MATCH: "L123S45"
1st part: 123
2nd part: 45

THERE IS A MATCH: "L1x23S4yZY5"
1st part: 1x23
2nd part: 4yZY5
```

You can play with it here: https://3v4l.org/nRnEd

Learn more about the regex and play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/pK9P9D/2